# Swap selected cells value due to typo

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an input dataset with typo errors and don't know how could I swap them back. Let say the data look like this

```
 A          B            C           D           E         F
   Yes         0            School      1           0.5       0.3
    1          No            1         Office       0.2        3.4
   No          1           University   1            4.7       4.2
   Yes         3             House      0            4.6        2.3
   0           Yes           0          House         4.5      3.1
```

Like, the typo has no rules, but it usually happen in 2 columns that is next to the other, some other are remain true while the other are typo. How could I normalize my data in such case? Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: "with typo errors" - what errors?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check first why data arrives in this format in the first place. Here is one possible solution, given mix is always between strings and numbers (if not it may be more complicated)

```
df["AB"] = df["A"] + "_" + df["B"]
df["A_"] = df["AB"].apply(lambda x: re.findall(r"\d+", x)[0])
df["B_"] = df["AB"].apply(lambda x: re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z]+", x)[0])
```

But then you will need to drop the original columns and rename the new ones. Hope this helps.